# What is this plant in England with large veined leaves and multi-part buds?

Tags: uk, plants, plant-identification

I was wondering if anyone could help me identify what this plant is? We have found it growing in our garden in England a few times and are unsure what it could be.

[image: Comfrey plant]

Comment: Certainly an OK question here - where about are you in England? (We get similar in our garden but we lump them under 'weed' - we're in the South)

Comment: I am in Yorkshire, must be a nationwide pest!

Comment: the definition of a weed is always ambiguous though, knowing the proper name would be interesting!

Comment: Not sure if any of these would be of help: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/gardening/tools-and-accessories/the-best-apps-to-identify-unknown-plants-and-flowers/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thick veins make me believe it is [Comfrey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comfrey).  Your image is of a young plant so it is hard to tell for sure.

It is and has been an important part of herbal treatments and gardening.  It is used across the world.

Comment: That is definitely one of the ones we get in our garden, but we tend to get rid of them. Interesting to know more about it :)

Comment: Word of caution, Foxgloves are very commonly mistaken for Comfrey...  foxgloves are very very toxic. Please edit this answer to reflect that! http://www.buzzardbushcraft.co.uk/2015/04/difference-between-young-comfrey-and.html?m=1

Comment: @JeffUK [foxgloce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitalis) is very different plant it grows tall and thin with small leaves, while comfrey grows low and wide with big leaves, While foxglove is very toxic, it would be inappropriate to try and list any or all of the plants that might get confused.  i.e. [lambs ear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stachys_byzantina) could be confused with either.

Comment: Comfrey and foxglove are commonly mistaken for each other more sources here http://www.motherearthliving.com/Gardening/green-patch-toxic-plant-lookalikes here  http://www.oardc.ohio-state.edu/weedguide/single_weed.php?id=30 and here https://millstreamgardens.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/plants-not-to-get-confused/

Comment: Possibly worth editing that into the post, but I can't see how they are mistaken, myself.

Comment: Mainly an issue when they're young; Foxgloves stay quite small and low to the ground until they near flowering, then they shoot upwards.   The pictures on the 'millstreamgardens' site make it quite clear how they can be confused for each other.  Especially if you only have one or the other, with both side by side the differences are more obvious.  (and obviously once the foxglove flower there is no doubt!)

Comment: @JeffUK You have done a lot of research on the subject. Rather then me editing my answer, would you write an answer of your own? based on what you have in the comments here, your answer would get my vote.